# Loading FontFace objects in _document.tsx

Tags: css, next.js

I have a number of `FontFace` items in `fonts/myFonts.js`:

```js
const fontFaces = [
  new FontFace('MyFont', "url('local/location.woff2') format('woff2')", {
    weight: '400',
    style: 'normal',
    ...
  }),
 ...
]

fontFaces.forEach((f) => document.fonts.add(f)); // would that even suffice?
```

Now, I try to put them into the header of my `pages/_document.tsx`:

```js
class MyDocument extends Document {
  render = () => (
    <Html>
      <Head>
        <script src="../fonts/myFonts.js" async />
        ...
      </Head>

      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

This doesn't seem to achieve anything:

- According to the brower console, `fonts/myFonts.js` is not found
- If it was found - is that actually the correct way to go? I'm not waiting for the fonts to be ready etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you put your `myFonts.js` file on you `public/` folder, then simply called the file.

```
<script src={`//${NEXT_PUBLIC_FRONTEND_HOST}/assets/js/fonts/myFonts.js`} />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This way, the `font.js` will be found, but I figure the fonts don't get really loaded. Maybe `ontFaces.forEach((f) => document.fonts.add(f));` is insuficent or the wrong approach at all?

Comment: hi, sorry for the late reply. i think i need you to get me a minimal reproduction link (maybe codesandbox or something) so i can tweak the code and get the solution/workaround for you.

Comment: I see. Well, I gave up on that approach for now. But thanks for your help anyway!